# Ansible Generate an array of numbers

Tags: ansible

My intention is to generate a list containing numbers from 1 to 22 and for that I wrote below Ansible script.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Generate sequance
      set_fact:
        mysequence: "{{ item | list }}"
      with_sequence: start=1 end=22

    - debug: var=mysequence
```

When I run the code I get this weird result

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Generate sequance] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=3)
ok: [localhost] => (item=4)
ok: [localhost] => (item=5)
ok: [localhost] => (item=6)
ok: [localhost] => (item=7)
ok: [localhost] => (item=8)
ok: [localhost] => (item=9)
ok: [localhost] => (item=10)
ok: [localhost] => (item=11)
ok: [localhost] => (item=12)
ok: [localhost] => (item=13)
ok: [localhost] => (item=14)
ok: [localhost] => (item=15)
ok: [localhost] => (item=16)
ok: [localhost] => (item=17)
ok: [localhost] => (item=18)
ok: [localhost] => (item=19)
ok: [localhost] => (item=20)
ok: [localhost] => (item=21)
ok: [localhost] => (item=22)

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "mysequence": [
        "2",
        "2"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I am using latest version of Ansible. Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

I need this list for another task. Here is a snippet:

```
- name: Reboot 22 VMs
  vmware_guest:
    validate_certs: false
    hostname: x.x.x.x
    username: user@vsphere.local
    password: PASSS
    datacenter: DC1
    folder: "DC1/vm/Pod-{{item[1]}}"
    name: "{{item[0]}}-Pod-{{item[1]}}"
    state: restarted
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_nested:
    - "{{myVarList}}"
    - [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]
```

Comment: What will you be eventually using this list of numbers for?  Is there a particular reason why you are trying to do this?  I suspect you should be using some alternative method, but more context would allow us to point you to something better.

Comment: I need this list for another task. `with_nested`:`- "{{myVarList}}"``-
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]`

Comment: Right, you need to explain why you need this list of numbers and what you wanted to accomplish.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Please see added information

Comment: This is the wrong approach. You need to use a dynamic inventory instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing is *weird* in your results: you set `mysequence` 22 times, the values of the first 21 iterations are overwritten, the last value is a string `22` converted to a list with `list` filter. In result you get two-element list with `2` and `2`.

What you wanted the task to look like is:

```
- name: Generate sequance
  set_fact:
    mysequence: "{{ mysequence | default([]) + [item | int] }}"
  with_sequence: start=1 end=22
```

---

But what you really wanted is a way of generating a list of integers in a Jinja2 template:

```
- set_fact:
    mysequence: "{{ range(1, 22 + 1) | list }}"
```

Comment: Nice answer.  Since the OP is mostly using the sequence in a string context, they could probably skip all the bits to convert it to integers though.  IE just going with only `{{ lookup('sequence', 'start=1 end=22').split(',')}}`

Comment: Yes, but the request was for a list of integers.